# Facebook login with open app from web browser

Tags: c#, facebook, authentication

I have a website using facebook login. Currently, when I click to Fb login button, it show a popup and request login. It's fine on desktop.

But on mobile, I need to open facebook app and request login, after login, it return my website from app. How to do this?

Thanks

Comment: That is not really possible; there is no connection between the mobile Facebook app, and whatever browser might be used.

Answer (score 0):

Use FB SDK for the app.
There is [React Native FBSDK](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) for React Native android app.
If you made an android app using java. Then use [Android FBSDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk).

Comment: But my web site using mvc c#. How can do it?

Comment: You can't. Those things are for native apps. Not for websites.

Comment: @WizKid 2020 it still can't do?